# Contents of SectionList visible from web-browser, but not iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm experiencing trouble using React-Native when constructing SectionList and filling it with information. It seems to display fine on the web-browser (Chrome), [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tLrX.png).

However, this doesn't seem to be the case when viewing the content on an iOS simulator/device. The section title does display, yet the contents do not. [Here's a screenshot directly from my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeP5p.png).

Here's the code used for each card:

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.english}>{props.english}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.other}>{props.other}</Text>
    </View>
    );
}
```

..and here's the code for SectionList:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SectionList sections= {[{
          title: "English", data: 
            [
                <Card english="English0" other="Other0"/>,
                <Card english="English1" other="Other1"/>,
                <Card english="English2" other="Other2"/>,
            ]
          }]}
        renderItem={
          ({item}) => <Text style={styles.box}>{item}</Text>
        }
        renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{section.title}</Text>}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Additionally, StyleSheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 5,
    backgroundColor:"#f1faee",
  },
  box: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    padding: 10,
    height: 150,
    width: "95%",
    backgroundColor:"#1d3557",
    borderColor:"#000000",
    shadowOffset:{ width: 3,  height: 3},
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOpacity: 0.4,
    borderRadius: 15,
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  english: {
    color:"#f1faee",
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  other: {
    color:"#f1faee",
    fontSize: 50,
  },
  sectionHeader: {
    paddingTop: 2,
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 2,
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    backgroundColor: "#f1faee"
  }
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be the case, am I missing something blatantly obvious? Apologies in advance as this is my first day with web/react-native development. If someone could put me in the right direction, it'd be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that.
I found the answer, I didn't need to wrap View around Card. JSX <> </> was suitable enough, and managed to get it working.

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
        <Text style={styles.english}>{props.english}{"\n"}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.other}>{props.other}</Text>
    </>
    );
}
```